# How can I add the constraint that regression parameters are orthogonal to a design matrix in an MCMC algorithm?

Tags: regression, markov-chain-montecarlo, orthogonal

Suppose I have a linear regression like
$$y_i=X\boldsymbol{\beta} + \alpha_i + \epsilon_i,$$
where $\epsilon_i\sim N(0,\sigma^2)$ are i.i.d. Further, suppose that I want to add the constraint that $\alpha_i$ is orthogonal to $X$. How can I implement this constraint in an MCMC algorithm?

Comment: at each step of the MCMC, after you have sampled $\alpha_i$ (but before evaluating the accept/reject criterion), project it along $\mathbf{X}$'s range. Using Python and Numpy, that looks like this: $\alpha \gets \alpha - \mathbf{X}@ \texttt{np.linalg.lstsq}(\mathbf{X},\alpha)$. For R, replace $\texttt{np.linalg.lstsq}$ with $\texttt{solve}$ (and $@$ with %*%). (this is assuming $\mathbf{X}$ has more rows than columns).

Comment: @JohnMadden I see. So, I don't need to propose values under this constraint? It is enough to propose values, then project it along $X$'s range? I suppose that means I cannot use a Gibbs update. Initially, I was using a normal prior for $\alpha_i$, but if I project the $\alpha_i$, then I don't think I get away with conjugacy.

Comment: Oh, I read your question too fast; my comment applies in the general Metropolis-Hastings case. In your case, you should place a singular Gaussian prior on $\alpha$; the posterior will still be a singular Gaussian and you can continue to enjoy closed form Gibbs updates.

Comment: @JohnMadden No worries at all. I can use a Metropolis-Hastings update - that's fine with me. However, if I can use a conjugate update that is obviously preferable. How would a singular Gaussian prior incorporate the orthogonal constraint?

Comment: Under the usual definitions $X\beta$ is an n-vector, but you're referring to a single element of it (the $i$-th); you might perhaps consider using "$x_i\beta$ (where $x_i$ is the $i$-th row of $X$)". Another possibility is "$(X\beta)_i$, the $i$-th element of $X\beta$".

Comment: @RonSnow closed form Gibbs sure does make life a lot easier; I would try to keep it :) To do a singular prior, you would choose a prior covariance matrix for $\alpha$ which has as range the same range as $\mathbf{X}$. Many choices are possible, but a ``default" one might be $\Sigma_\alpha = v \mathbf{U}\mathbf{U}^\top$, where $v$ is a scalar hyperparameter and $\mathbf{U}$ is an orthonormal basis for the right nullspace of $\mathbf{X}$ ...

Comment: ... which may be computed using an SVD as such in numpy: $\texttt{np.linalg.svd(X, full_matrices = True)[2][:,P:]}$, where $P$ is the number of variables. Do note that much material treating multivariate normal distributions assumes they are nonsingular.

Comment: @JohnMadden Do you have an recommendations for a value for $v$ that is as "vague" as possible?

Comment: This is the analog to the $\sigma^2$ of the independent ($\sigma^2\mathbf{I}$) or g prior ($\sigma^2(\mathbf{X}^\top\mathbf{X})^{-1}$); in my view the correct approach is to perform a sensitivity analysis by trying a logarithmically spaced grid of values. But in general higher variance is less informative.

Comment: @JohnMadden Perfect, thank you for your help! I still have more questions (mostly how the singular Gaussian prior affects the overall model). Are there any resources that you recommend to read up on this type of work?

Comment: I don't know of any material that specifically treats your case, but the intrinsic CAR model is somewhat kind of similar ($\alpha$ is just constrained to be mean zero, aka orthogonal to the vector of 1s): https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0167947321000980

Comment: @JohnMadden Great. Thank you so much for your help! If you want to post your first comment as an answer, I can accept that!

Comment: I'll write an actual answer if I get the chance.